# My custom wp-admin php files stopped working

Tags: php, wp-admin

I created several custom php files in my "wp-admin" folder two years ago. They have worked fine for two years. Now, they don't show my custom admin panels. Instead, the home page of my website appears. Even if I make a copy of an original WordPress php file and rename it to something else it does not work anymore. Earlier if I made a copy of, for example, "profile.php" and renamed it to "test.php" it still worked. Now it does not.

If I rename the file "about.php" to "about-1.php" and paste the url "https://example.com/wp-admin/about-1.php" in my browser while I'm logged in to WordPress, then my home page appears instead of the original content of the php file. This method used to work fine earlier but now it does not.

What could be the reason and how could I solve it?

Thanks.

Comment: you should never modify the wp-admin or wp-includes folders, you need to port your custom admin files to instead be plugins that use the correct API, e.g. `add_settings_page( ....`. My expectation is that when you update WordPress all your files and modifications would be erased, and that these changes would have been flagged by security software as intrusions/breaches. Those folders have well defined contents and checksums

Answer (score 0):

As Tom noted, it's never safe to edit WP Core files, including any of the contents of wp-admin or wp-includes.

What happened? Your site may have auto-updated, and any update to Core would have overwritten your changes. Or, even if your site didn't auto-update, it could be that your host has recently locked down those folders so you can't just access the files directly.

How to proceed? Check your own backups, or if you don't have one, check with your host. Many hosts offer backups for a fee, even if you pay them after the date you want to pull backups from - i.e. many of them are already storing backups and just not making them available until you pay. Once you have those backups, it may be quite a process to go through all the files, compare them to the Core versions, and pull all that functionality out into separate plugin files so that your code is safe and doesn't get overwritten when Core is updated.

Comment: Thanks. Originally I put my own php files in the wp-adim folder because I did not want to include the pages in the dashboard menu, and this way I could put "https://example.com/wp-admin/myadminpage.php" into any anchor tag. But now I could not even open a single php file that only says "Hello World" from the wp-admin folder, only the original php files worked that were included with my WordPress installation. So now I included all my code in my theme's functions.php but removed them from the dashboard, this way I can reference them by https://example.com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=myadminpage.php